# How to define every five minutes to run jobs

Tags: jobs, playframework

How to define every five minutes to run jobs

in the play.jobs.every class ,it define an example every("1h") to run job every hour,bu i want to run every 5 minutes,how to define this.

i try the every("5m") or every("0.1h") ,play reports internal error.

Answer (score 18):

Short answer:

You can use either of the following

```
@Every("5mn")
@Every("5min")
```

---

Long answer:

The `@Every` annotation uses the `play.libs.Time` class, and specifically the `parseDuration` method to determine how often the job is scheduled.

If you look at the source code, the Javadoc states...

```
   /**
     * Parse a duration
     * @param duration 3h, 2mn, 7s
     * @return The number of seconds
     */
```

This would suggest that you should specify your code as `@Every("5mn")`

If you look deeper into the code, it determines that the time is in minutes by using the following regular expression.

```
"^([0-9]+)mi?n$"
```

So, this states that either of the following are valid

```
@Every("5mn")
@Every("5min")
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using "5min" in your annotation instead:

```
@Every("5min")
```